# How do I get a Samsung SCX3200 multifunction printer/scanner working?

Tags: printing, scanner

I bought samsung scx3200 multifunction printer i think that printing is easy as Ubuntu define the printer by default but what about scanning i have found a default installed program called `simple scan` but it didn't recognize the scanner
[image: simple scan]
and i have installed the driver from [here](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/printers-multifunction/monochrome-laser-multifunction-printers-faxes/SCX-3200/XSS/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=support) but the same
[image: samsung driver]
then what to do ???

Comment: there is a long thread here on these packages - this post looks interesting.  I dont have your printer to test with hence the comment.  Good luck: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9887879&postcount=500

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For 11.10

Download the official Samsung Unified Driver from [this page](http://www.samsung.com/it/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_ia_cd=06010300&prd_mdl_cd=&prd_mdl_name=SCX-3200)

Installed the Samsung drivers following the steps in the Samsung manual, [here](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201006/20100607163009421/EN/english/start_here.htm) (see the chapter "Getting started", section "Supplied software");

Add in `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` these two lines:

```
# Samsung SCX-3200
usb 0x04e8 0x3441
```

and in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` these two lines:

```
# Samsung SCX-3200
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3441", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9887879&postcount=500)

Comment: sorry haven't seen your answer while writing the answer to other's

Answer (score 7):

#### For 12.04

In 12. 04 the printer worked out of the box. To get the scanner working I didn't have to download anything. I just edited a few files:

I added to `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` the following:

```
# Samsung SCX-3200
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3441", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

And to `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`, I added

```
#Samsung SCX-3200
usb 0x04e8 0x3441
```

Then I did a

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Unplugged and plugged the scanner and all was working.

note: for SCX-3405 use 344f instead of 3441

Comment: this is necessary in ubuntu 20.04 again to get the scanner to work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ but the first file is located in /etc/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules meanwhile

Answer (score 4):

As explained [in ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=341621) a nice guy prepared **[a repository](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/) for easy driver installation**.
Very important: you must have completely removed all prior installations of the Unified Linux Driver before using the packages.
Here I quote his instructions:

1. Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list, by editing the file using sudo, or by using Synaptic:

   ```
   deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra
   ```
2. Install the GPG key for the repository. Execute in a terminal as sudo:

   ```
   wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Refresh your repository listings (apt-get update or in a GUI), and then you should see the NEW suld-* and OLD samsungmfp-* packages corresponding to the Samsung Unified Linux Driver.
4. Install the latest available drivers `suld-driver-4.01.17`.
   Printer and Scanner should now be usable with the distribution now.
   If you also would like to have the Samsung Unified Driver Configuration GUI, do
   install `suld-configurator-2-qt4`.
5. If you are trying to use your printer as a scanner, you will need to add yourself to the "lp" group after installing the appropriate packages. You will then to log out and back in for the change to take effect.

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G lp yourname
   ```

Now your scanner should work with simple scan. If not lookup above mentioned page for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

#### For 10.04

1- Downloaded the official Samsung Unified Driver from [this page](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/printers-multifunction/monochrome-laser-multifunction-printers-faxes/SCX-3200/XSS/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=support).
2- install the Samsung drivers by accurately following the steps in the Samsung manual.
[image: samsung-site]
[image: manual]

3- open the terminal and write this command `gksu gedit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`, 
       write down the password and add this two lines to the file:

```
                 # Samsung SCX-3200
                 usb 0x04e8 0x3441
```

it should be near to this
[image: samsung-driver]
       save the file and close it.
4-also write this command in the terminal `gksu gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`
       and add these two lines:

```
       # Samsung SCX-3200
       ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3441", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

   save and close the file.
```

it should be near this
[image: samsung-driver]
restart and it should work.
a picture of my scanner
[image: scanner2]
[image: scanner1]
                                         Thanks to @fossfreedom and [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9887879&postcount=500)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the printer from `http://localhost:631`, as the samsung configurator installation insists on port ipp.

When I did this, the CUPS server at the time recognized the USB printer, and put the PPD in `/usr/share/ppd/custom/samsung`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did based on the advice of a friend. I have Samsung SCX-3405FW. Printer has been installed easily but with the scanner I have a problem. Here it is how I have resolved the problem:

LAN-based scanners

The scanner is connected directly to the network without any intermediary computer.
Samsung ALL-in-One devices

Add The Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and adding the following line:

```
deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra
```

Be advised that most probably you can not do the edit with gedit. Open the `sources.list` file with Software & Updates and add the line at the APT window.

Then install the GPG key, update, install scanner driver & discover your scanner:

```
sudo wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install samsungmfp-scanner 
sudo /opt/Samsung/mfp/bin/netdiscovery --all --scanner >.samsung.netdiscovery
```

Hope this helps