# Samsung SCX - 3205w printing wierd symbols

Tags: printing, samsung

I come here today with a problem that's kind of driving me crazy :p
I have a Samsung SCX - 3205w laser printer, and it was working fine with Ubuntu 11.04 but when Ubuntu 11.10 was launched this printer started having problems.

I installed it looking at the guide from : [How do I get a Samsung SCX3200 multifunction printer/scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88700/how-to-define-my-samsung-scx3200-multifunction-printer)

So here is the problem, 85% of the times I try to print something it just prints weird symbols, like little hearts, smiles, clubs, spades, anyway a lot of symbols.

It starts by printing a blank page, then every single page after that has symbols and not the text/image I was trying to print

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 at the moment and the problem stays the same, tried unstalling and reinstalling using the Samsung Unified Driver from the web page, I even made a clean format to my PC when Installed the Ubuntu 12.04 and nothing, I'm beeing force to handle my printing from a Windows XP Virtual enviroment (VirtualBox)

Any help will be appreciatted and if you need any info about my system just ask

Comment: Seems that the Unified Linux Driver is outdated in the new OS versions, I'm going to try the Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository from http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ and I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: No luck with that :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP posted:

> After the first update from the repositories in http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ my Samsung Printer started working beautifully,no more weird symbols, no more lags, only perfect printing :)