# Not able to use scan functionality of Samsung SCX 3200 series MFP [12.04]

Tags: 12.04, samsung, scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Samsung SCX3200 multifunction printer/scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88700/how-do-i-get-a-samsung-scx3200-multifunction-printer-scanner-working)

I was able to scan in 11.10 thanks to this thread here- 
[How do I get a Samsung SCX3200 multifunction printer/scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88700/how-to-define-my-samsung-scx3200-multifunction-printer)

But ever since I have installed a fresh version of 12.04, there has been no detection of scanner. Kindly help me with the issue. Thanks in advance :)